# symfony 2 how to pass array collection to input select

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Hi i am tying pass array collection (method getProjects() returns it) to form (select input) and fail. This code returns exception - A "__toString()" method was not found on the objects of type "Tasker\WebBundle\Entity\Project" passed to the choice field.

Can anybody help? Is needed transformer? Or what is right way?

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/pridaj", name="web.task.add")
 * @Template()
 */
public function addAction(Request $request)
{

    $task = new Task;

    /** @var User $loggedUser */
    $loggedUser = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(new AddTaskType(), $task, ['user' => $loggedUser]);

    if ($form->handleRequest($request) && $form->isValid()) {

        // some stuff
    }


    return [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ];
}
```

Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('project', 'entity', [
            'label' => 'Projekt:',
            'class' => 'TaskerWebBundle:Project',
            'choices' => $options['user']->getProjects(),
            'placeholder' => 'Označte projekt',
        ])
    // ....

 }


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{

    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'user',
    ));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'user' => null,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `__ToString()` to your Project class

```
Tasker\WebBundle\Entity\Project

class Project
{
    ....

    function __toString() {
        return $this->getName(); //or whatever string you have
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another answer, because you do not have to add `__toString()` to your Project class.  The Symfony [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) allows you to specify which property/field to use for displaying.  So instead of `__toString()` you could specify the property in the form configuration like so:

```
$builder
    ->add('project', 'entity', [
        'label' => 'Projekt:',
        'class' => 'TaskerWebBundle:Project',
        'choices' => $options['user']->getProjects(),
        'placeholder' => 'Označte projekt',
        'property' => 'name'
    ])
```

If you check [this part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) of the Symfony documentation you will see that `__toString()` is automatically called only if you do not specify the `property`.